# How do health enchantments get recalculated when one of them expires

Tags: hearthstone

Imagine, minion, say Raptor, with 2 health. I will use `2/2` notation to indicate the current/maximum health.

- Raptor gets `+3` health as a temporary buff, making it `5/5`.
- Then Raptor is damaged by `4`, reducing it to `1/5`.
- Then Raptor is permanently buffed with `+6`, making it `7/11`.

When (at the end of the turn) temp buff expires, per Advanced Rulebook, - enchantments are recalculated from scratch.

- What does that mean in practice ?
- That we will get `4/8` Raptor ? Or `7/8` ?
- Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporary health buffs also serve as a healing. Following this I would say it becomes a 7/8.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3kg107/comment/cux4svz) you can find someone complaining about this and also a good explanation by user OracleWawa.

He had a similar problem as you do. He had two damaged murlocs which got buffed by a warleader but upon removal of the warleader the murlocs did not drop back down in health.

This explains the interaction:

> If an aura buff provider like Stormwind Champion or Murloc Warleader
>   is on board and buffs a minion who wasn't at his full health (or you
>   hit that minion down to like 2 HP and then remove Stormwind Champion
>   from the board) the HP will stay the same. It's a thing you need to
>   learn.
>
> Basically minion's HP will increase when it's max HP increases too
>   with any kind of way (Power Word: Shield, Stormwind Champion etc.),
>   but if minion's max HP would be decreased but not below his current
>   HP, his current HP won't change. And technically any HP buff,
>   including aura minion buffs like Stormwind Champion are max HP buffs.

Comment: hmm.. interesting that it also applies to auras, like `Murloc Warleader`'s

Comment: on a second read - no it just **cannot** be `7/11` - as that was the state before temporary +3 got removed. Do you mean `7/8` ?

Comment: Oops yes, my mistake. Wrote it from my phone. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Worth noting that Murloc Warleader got nerfed and isn't a good example of this anymore. Stormwind is!